# Activating Macro view button sends excel in non-responding mode

Tags: excel, vba, macros

In Excel 2013: macro was working fine until today.  Now, I can open the "Personal.xlsb" file, but I cannot use the Macro view button anymore, all I get is Excel in unresponding mode; and then, only way is to stop Excel entirely.  When I go in design mode, I cannot access the macro registry at all (trying to do so results in the same unresponding state). I rebooted the PC entirely, did not help.

Pb seems specific to one specific "Personal.xlsb" file (I replaced the incriminated file with another "Personal" file in the XSTART folder and Excel macros worked just fine with a different .xlsb file).  So I am suspecting a file corruption pb.  If that is the case, is it possible to recover the original macros, or at least crack the macro file open and get a copy of the original coding?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to get back your code if you manage to open the workbook from a macro in another workbook. Give this a shot:

- create a folder where you will get the recovered code modules. Let's say "C:\myRecoveredCode". Put in a copy of your corrupt file "Personal.xlsb"
- In Excel Options, `Trust Center Settings`, Check `Trust Access to the VBA project object module`
- create a fresh workbook, copy/paste and run the following macro:

  ```
  Sub TryRecovery()
      myFolder = "C:\myRecoveredCode\"
      Set wb = CreateObject(myFolder & "Personal.xlsb")
      For Each comp In wb.VBProject.VBComponents
          comp.Export myFolder & comp.Name
      Next
      wb.Close False
  End Sub
  ```

If all goes well, you will have files a set of files that you can edit, or import to another workbook.

Comment: Probably requires Trust Center allowing access to the VBProject Object Model.

Comment: Then, import modules 1 at a time, save/close/re-open until you find the offending module(s), at least then OP can debug or ask Q specific to the code which may be causing it.

Comment: @DavidZemens Exactly, I forgot to say it. I will add this note. thanks.

Comment: @DavidZemens As for the second part, I hope the OP will do it and come back with some more information. Form the time being we cross our fingers and hope that they can recover the lost code. :)

Comment: Indeed. Without knowing (or really, having any idea) what sort of code resides in this file, it is impossible to speculate about root cause, and of course it may simply be a corrupted file.